# Performing a function inside another page

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, win-universal-app

I am developing a windows universal app , I have 2 pages :

1. `MainPage.xaml`
2. `page2.xaml`

I have a button in `Mainpage.xaml` which its code is :

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(page2));
```

in that `page2` I do some stuff using `page2` elements

the app works properly til here.
but I want to do the same thing without navigating to page 2 , so I did something like that:

```
page2 p = new page2();    
p.doStuff();
```

but in `page2` when the code executes the first line the app crashes.

how can I do such thing ??

Comment: What you mean by crashes? Is there an error message? If so what does the message say, and on which line does the error appear?

Comment: I tried to catch an exception but there's not even an exception

Comment: @KaramNajjar can you provide a full (minimal) repro? If I do the minimum with the above I don't see an error. There are probably better ways to do what you're trying to do but you'll also benefit from understanding why you're getting the error you report. If the error is in the line where you create an instance of `page2` the problem is probably with the XAML or something else in the constructor of the page. If the exception comes when you call `doStuff()` then the method will contain something causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you centralize the logic of the processing on a shared ViewModel method. That way all work is in one place and can be accessed by both pages.

The problem you are running into is that initializing another page on the stack means that the stack page is not being properly started and fails.